# How to understand `tf.constant` and `tf.Variable`?

Tags: tensorflow

1. How can I learn about the type of `K = tf.random_normal([2, 3])`? Is it a `tf.constant` or `tf.Variable` or `tf.placeholder`?
2. By the way, whether `tf.constant` means trainable and `tf.constant` means untrainable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding 1.):
K is simply a tensor object of the specified shape with values drawn from a normal distribution. It cannot access the methods of the other classes like for example get_variable or assign. Therefore, unless you declare it explicitly like one of these three, it is simply a tensor.

Regarding 2.):
tf.constants are (unsurprisingly) constant. That means they do NOT contain trainable parameters. For this purpose, there is tf.Variable. Please note that even variables can be set to be not trainable through the use of the corresponding flag.

Comment: That great, thanks a lot. Before this, it's just my guess that "`tf.constant`- trainable, and `tf.Variable` - untrainable". But now, I know some more.